# How can give css effects to ul li elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new in jQuery and I couldn't gain giving CSS animation effects to ul li elements when clicking 
filter buttons like mixitup(https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/).

So I want to give css3 animation effect every clicking to filter buttons.

To illustrate this,

Filter html example:

```
<div class="control-bar sandbox-control-bar">
    <div class="group">
        <label>Filter:</label>
        <span class="btn filter active" data-filter="all">All</span>
        <span class="btn filter" data-filter=".category-1">Blue</span>
        <span class="btn filter" data-filter=".category-2">Green</span>
        <span class="btn filter" data-filter="none">None</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Our ul li grid elements:

```
<ul class="grid">
    <li class="category-1"> 
        <img src="img/thumb/1.png" alt="img01"/>
    </li>
    <li class="category-2">
        <img src="img/thumb/2.png" alt="img02"/>
    </li>
    <li class="category-3">
        <img src="img/thumb/3.png" alt="img02"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So I want to gain give CSS animate effect to li element which has filter button data-filter class when filter button clicked.

For clear understanding my problem you can inspect mixitup(https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/).

Thanks for every help.

Comment: post your JQuery codes

Comment: I havent got jquery code.In fact I want to learn how can we write jquery code for giving css animation to the elements.

Comment: This is very hard without any working code or jsfiddle to understand what you want

Comment: Add your woking code as a snippet to your question. Click `edit` below your post, then the button labelled `<>`.